# Convert from Radians to Degrees in Java

Tags: java, math, geometry

I'm trying to get the alpha angle in degrees from x,y when user creates an object.

I wrote the following constructor:

```
public class Point
{
    private double _radius , _alpha;    

    public Point ( int x , int y )
    {
        _radius = Math.sqrt ( Math.pow(x,2) + Math.pow (y,2) ) ;
        _alpha = ( ( Math.atan (y/x) ) * 180 ) / Math.PI;
    }

}
```

1. Am I right that _alpha is now an angle in degrees instead of radians that I got from the atan() method ?
2. Is there a simple way to do so ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Why not use the built-in method `Math.toDegrees()`, it comes with the Java SE.

Comment: Have you meant: _alpha = Math.toDegrees( (Math.atan (y/x)) ); ??

Answer (score 5):

The idea looks ok, but I would suggest using [Math.atan2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2%28double,%20double%29) instead of `Math.atan`.

Comment: @Master C: It is called like `Math.atan2(y,x)`. Please follow the URL in my answer to see the actual javadoc for details.

Answer (score 1):

This should be by far the shortest and simplest way:

```
        _radius = Math.hypot(x, y);
        _alpha = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x));
```

Keep in mind that when computed this way, `_alpha` will have values between -180 and 180 degrees.