# Math.acos(0.26311) gives 1.3045519539106323. But using calculator we get 74.74degree. How to Convert the value to degrees?

Tags: java

Using the code `Math.acos(0.26311)` gives 1.3045519539106323. 
But using calculator, we get 74.74 degree.

How to Convert the value to degrees? 
Please help.

Comment: The value is in radians.

Comment: Math class has a method to convert radians to degrees (and vice-versa).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic trigonometry.

Comment: Is this Java, C++ or C? They're very different languages.

Comment: Thank you so much all for such a quick response:) This is my first post on stack overflow. This question is was asked for java language. Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(double)) worked!!! Thank you so much :)

Comment: This [seems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872998/math-acos0-26311-gives-1-3045519539106323-but-using-calculator-we-get-74-74de#comment27851854_18873034) to be Java.

Answer (score 2):

The result you are getting is in [Radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian).

The formula to convert radians to degrees can be found here:

[Convert from Radians to Degrees in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763841/convert-from-radians-to-degrees-in-java)

And is very simple. Use built-in static function from Math class:

```
Math.toDegrees()
```

The same goes for argument of `sin()` `cos()` etc - it is in radians, not in degrees, so you should convert value from degrees to radians before calling it. You can do it using

```
Math.toRadians()
```

Comment: Please answer, sin(35) should be 0.5735, but method Math.sin(35) returns -0.428182669496151!! Why so, I am in the middle of programming and I am stuck here.

Comment: @user2791560 I extended my answer. The argument is also in radians, not in degrees.

Answer (score 1):

This value in radians. To get value in radian you should use following formula 180*Mathacos(0.26311)/Math.PI

Comment: An easier formular is x*180/Math.PI

Comment: Thank you so much all for such a quick response:) This is my first post on stack overflow. This question is was asked for java language. Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(double)) worked!!! Thank you so much :)