# Convert radiant to degrees

Tags: java

Is there a method JAVA to convert a radiant in degrees (° ' '')? 
For example radiant = - 272,7’  degrees:  4° 33’ S.
Anybody can help me?

Thank for your answers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert from Radians to Degrees in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763841/convert-from-radians-to-degrees-in-java)

Comment: Do you mean convert radians to degrees, ie.e you want Pi (3.14) to return 180?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that it is *radians* not radiants.

A full circle is 360 degrees, or 2 Pi radians. 
So a radian is 360/2Pi degrees.
So, you could do `(radians * 2 * Math.PI) / (2 * 180)` 
i.e. `(radians * Math.PI) / (180)`

Or use `Math.toDegrees(radians)` which involves less magic numbers and spells out what you are doing.

---

Just for clarity, if you have a number in degrees and want to go the other way, converting this to radians, note you have 
A full circle is 360 degrees, or 2 Pi radians. 
So a degree is 2Pi/360 radians.
So, you could do `(radians * 2 * 180) / (2 * Math.PI)` 
i.e. `(radians * 180) / (Math.PI)`

Or use `Math.toRadians(degrees)` which involves less magic numbers and spells out what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Math.toDegrees()` static function as below:

```
double deg = Math.toDegrees(2.0); // Returns 114.59155902616465
deg = Math.toDegrees(Math.PI); // Returns 180.0
```

Comment: I tried Math.toDegrees(90.0) but result is: 5156.620156177409

Comment: 90 radians is quite a few degrees. What do you expect?

Comment: Because 90 radians is more than a full circle so your answer will be greater than 360 degrees. Obviously you need to pass in your own radians value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Math.toDegrees()
```

Link in stack:

[Convert from Radians to Degrees in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763841/convert-from-radians-to-degrees-in-java)